# write a Query to get the total amount balance for each Transaction ID where the Balance is calculated as Charges-Payments-Adjustments?

Tags: sql

```
create table #t1(
td varchar(100),
tid int, 
tt varchar(100), 
amount decimal, 
userr varchar(100))

insert into #t1 values
('11-05-2020',1, 'charges', 100, 'john smith'),
('12-06-2020',2, 'charges', 200, 'tayler grand'),
('13-06-2020',3, 'charges', 500, 'sushan'),
('14-05-2020',1, 'Payments', 50, 'john smith'),
('15-05-2020',1, 'adjustments', 250, 'john smith'),
('16-05-2020',3, 'Payments', 100, 'sushan')
```

Comment: show us what did you try and and what's the issue you are facing.

Comment: Also please add the sample expected output from given data.

Comment: Please read the [help] articles, especially "[ask]".